# Why packed into generic omit behave differently from non packed?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

When i am trying to omit properties outside of generic it works fine, but it breaks inside generic. Basically the problem is that `Omit<Thing, 'key1' | 'key2'>` turns into `Omit<Thing, 'key1'> | Omit<Thing, 'key2'>` and typescript does not allow to use even keys that are both in `Omit<Thing, 'key1'>` and in `Omit<Thing, 'key2'>`

[live demo: typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=5&pln=23&pc=29#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4EEEOBgZQQjGDgG8BYAKDjgEsATAQgC44A7AVwFsAjYFADcNOjACepNnDQwo9DgHMRtRFGAoYwRlhjSAIpuAq6XMIyM697Q1pUBfGjQmk4AaWDi0AdQAW9BF8CXwguJEYAIWAAeR56GC1GOABeOAAiJjS4AB90hHVLXSzctLMLRKKVZ0kyHDxCYlJveN9Y+MSASSTUgAUAgGsAHjr8NCISYAAadJdgYryCiph50vNC5YA+KupZuDaYDoAzADkIGGOwpEHROABRDhh48UmbgAkIcMEX1Q8vABUIPtvhsUu5PGgAfs4KAtBxGJh+p4IIc7g8njcAPx7OIwQbvT5Qaa-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-nDUUGxrluO77tQh7HthHAXlA643plQHAHhFCmbV75oJ+37BbsLpQDwKBIGFqSKv4gTBKE4RRDK2jQiAsLwnAiLiKh1lDpi2LxD1EpDs0MCtJq2hdES4JKndqqPRq7TaKJcDsL9Eyg+DSOMF0wULfAp3nZdkWcNARNXTtL5lvth3UD+NBAA)

```js
export class AccessScope {
  id!: number;
  type!: string;
  createdAt!: Date;
  updatedAt!: Date;
}

type KeysWhichShouldBeOmitted = "id" | "createdAt" | "updatedAt";

type AccessScopeWithOmittedId = Pick<AccessScope, "type" | "createdAt" | "updatedAt">;

type OmitIfNotNull<
  Entity,
  Holder,
  KeysToOmit,
> = KeysToOmit extends keyof Entity
  ? Omit<Holder, KeysToOmit>
  : Holder;

type brokenType1 = OmitIfNotNull<
    AccessScope,
    AccessScopeWithOmittedId,
    KeysWhichShouldBeOmitted
>

// Type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'brokenType1'.
//   Property 'createdAt' is missing in type '{ type: string; }' but required in type 'Omit<Pick<AccessScope, "createdAt" | "updatedAt" | "type">, "updatedAt">'.(2322)
const brokenVar1: brokenType1 = {
    type: 'asd'
}

// brokenType2 is fully visible version of brokenType1
type brokenType2 = Omit<Pick<AccessScope, "type" | "createdAt" | "updatedAt"> & Record<never, never>, "id">
        | Omit<Pick<AccessScope, "type" | "createdAt" | "updatedAt"> & Record<never, never>, "createdAt">
        | Omit<Pick<AccessScope, "type" | "createdAt" | "updatedAt"> & Record<never, never>, "updatedAt">


// Type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'brokenType1'.
//   Property 'createdAt' is missing in type '{ type: string; }' but required in type 'Omit<Pick<AccessScope, "createdAt" | "updatedAt" | "type">, "updatedAt">'.(2322)
const brokenVar2: brokenType2 = {
    type: 'asd'
}

type normalType = KeysWhichShouldBeOmitted extends keyof AccessScope
  ? Omit<AccessScopeWithOmittedId, KeysWhichShouldBeOmitted>
  : AccessScopeWithOmittedId

const normalType: normalType = {
    type: 'asd'
}
```

I've tried to add all kind of strange variations of extending `OmitIfNotNull`'s parameters

```
type OmitIfNotNull<
  Entity extends Holder,
  Holder extends Record<string, any>,
  KeysToOmit extends keyof Entity,
> = KeysToOmit extends keyof Entity
  ? Omit<Holder, KeysToOmit>
  : Holder;
```

Comment: Use `[KeysToOmit] extends [keyof Entity]` to prevent distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is caused by the distributive nature of [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). You can disable this behavior by wrapping both sides of the `extends` clause in square brackets:

```
export class AccessScope {
  id!: number;
  type!: string;
  createdAt!: Date;
  updatedAt!: Date;
}

type KeysWhichShouldBeOmitted = "id" | "createdAt" | "updatedAt";

type AccessScopeWithOmittedId = Pick<AccessScope,
                                     "type" | "createdAt" | "updatedAt">;

type OmitIfNotNull<
  Entity,
  Holder,
  KeysToOmit,
> = [KeysToOmit] extends [keyof Entity]
  ? Omit<Holder, KeysToOmit>
  : Holder;

type noLongerBrokenType = OmitIfNotNull<
    AccessScope,
    AccessScopeWithOmittedId,
    KeysWhichShouldBeOmitted
>

const noLongerBrokenVar: noLongerBrokenType = {
    type: 'asd'
}
```

---

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4EEEOBgZQQjGDgG8BYAKDjgEsATAQgC44A7AVwFsAjYFADcNOjACepNnDQwo9DgHMRtRFGAoYwRlhjSAIpuAq6XMIyM697Q1pUBfGjQmk4AaWDi0AdQAW9BF8CXwguJEYAIWAAeR56GC1GOABeOAAiJjS4AB90hHVLXSzctLMLRKKVZ0kyHDxCYlJveN9Y+MSASSTUgAUAgGsAHjr8NCISYAAadJdgYryCiph50vNC5YA+KupZuDaYDoAzADkIGGOwpEHROABRDhh48UmbgAkIcMEX1Q8vABUIPtvhsUnAANq-NAA-YAXTgoC0HEYmDB-U8EEOdweTxhNwA-Hs4jBBu9PlBppDoUSNjd2KTGIJtrsOBAADIQJSCCJQCBojh-Gqg-ZHU7nS7XVR0EYNCbfOhS3CjcZNFr7TqMOXyyF+AJBEJhSIxImJGg06g0YgcWScNkcxRcnl8gBqKCg7BZ7M5UG5vOA-MFqSokrgs3YAHJ0IwwzR7EA)</sup>